# How do I set (!) in handlebars?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have this json:

```
"bg-image": {
   "sm": "",
   "md": "",
   "unique" : ""
}
```

And I have this code:

```
{{#if bg-image }}
    <style>
        @media screen and (max-width:642px) {
            .masthead {
                background-image: url({{bg-image.sm}});
            }
        }
        @media screen and (min-width:643px) {
            .masthead {
                background-image: url({{bg-image.md}});
            }
        }
    </style>
{{/if}}
```

But I want to do something like:

```
{{#if !bg-image.unique}}// then set bg-image.sm or bg-image.md {{/if}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [unless](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#conditionals), since `!property` is not valid syntax.

```
{{#unless bg-image.unique}}{{/unless}}
```

You can check the code for `unless` in [here](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/7535e48a7969229f44489124a8ef07bd17363f06/lib/handlebars/helpers/if.js#L17)